# Making a 'hash' of two floats

Tags: algorithm, hash

I have two 32-bit floating point numbers. I want to keep a count of how often any combination of the two occurs. I could technically do this by concatenating them into a string and use a regular hash map to keep track of the count, but the overhead of that is considerable in my application, so I was thinking if there would be a better way. I don't need to keep the full precision of a 32 bit float, and I know that one number is never > 10, and the other never > 100. So I could technically multiple the first by 10000, the second by 1000, cast the result to int to chop off anything after the comma, bit-shift the first nr 16 bits and & them together into an integer. I could then allocate an array of MAX_INT elements and use the integer I just created as an index into that array.

However, that would leave me with a 2GB array, most of which would be empty, so I'd like to avoid that. I was wondering if there are any hashing algorithms that go about this in a more sophisticated way, or any data structures that work in a 'tiered' way, like a tree where a lookup is first done on a combination of the first digits of each number, then on the second numbers and so on, so that no room needs to be allocated for any combinations that aren't known yet. (There is probably a problem with this exact approach, it's just an example of the direction I'm thinking in). Or any other way is fine too - like maybe a more sophisticated way of hashing two floats together, in such a way that the result is scaled between 0 and some number, where the chose of that 'some number' would give me a way to tune the max size of the lookup table in memory.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use a dictionary (hash table, hash map, ...). Which language are you asking about?

Comment: What about a data strucutre like trie?

Comment: That sounds like a good use case for bloom filters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter (also be aware that multiplying floats might not keep the accuracy you're looking for)

Comment: I agree with @trincot. It sounds like you're overcomplicating it. In many languages a simple hash map can use floats as keys, even pairs of floats.

Comment: You don't say anything about how many elements you have or what their distribution is like. Of that 2GB how many cells would be filled? What does the distribution of counts look like? And why are you comparing floats anyway when they may be subject to precision errors?

Answer (score -1):

You could copy the floats to one buffer and than hash that buffer, like this (this is c/c++):

```
int hashNumbers(float a, float b){
    char bytes[2 * sizeof(float)];

    memcpy(bytes, &a, sizeof(float));
    memcpy(bytes + sizeof(float), &b, sizeof(float));

    //I don't know your implementation of the actual hash function
    return hash(bytes, 2 * sizeof(float)); //assuming the hash function would take in an array of bytes with its size.
    //I don't know it's output type here. I'm assuming it's an int.
}
```

As for your has function you could use the modulo, if you for example just take the int which has 2^32 possibilities and that do `x = x % 100`, that would leave you with 100 possibilities as to what x could be.

If instead of 100 you would take a number which is a power of 2(2, 4, 8, 16, etc). You could accelerate this by instead of using modulo, you use [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C). By doing: `x = x >> 24`. You now only have 256 possibilities for x.